# Ignore response from Mule HTTP outbound endpoint and continue processing

Tags: http, mule

I have a simple Mule flow where I receive an XML message via an HTTP endpoint and then do some processing on it. One of the first steps is to send the message via another outbound HTTP endpoint to a web service. The service just saves the message and does no processing on it. Therefore I effectively want to ignore the return value of the outbound endpoint and continue processing the message that was originally received. I tried making the endpoint on-way, but then my current Mule message becomes empty.

How do I call a endpoint, but ignore any return and continue processing with my original message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `<wiretap>`: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-WireTap

Or use `<async>` scope: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Async+Scope+Reference

Or use an `<enricher>` if you want store the response in a variable but leave the current payload alone: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Message+Enricher

Note that wiretap and enricher are synchronous and will block further processing where async won't.

Answer (score 0):

In this case Async should be a better option.

Async in Mule helps to continue with the processing ignoring the results of the message processors called inside the async.

```
ex:
<flow name="sample" >
  <http:inbound-endpoint ...... />
   ....  Some processing.....
   <async>
      <http:outbound-endpoint  ....... />
   </async>
   ......  Continue with the processing with the original message....

 </flow>
```

Hope this helps.